# Why DataGrip automatically creates Foreign Key relation when 'table_id' column is added

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

Not long ago I started using DataGrip from Jetbrains, I am using postgres

when I add column 'table_id' foreign key relation is automaitcally is created between tables, though I didn't add any `FOREIGN KEY` statements. Do you know why relation is created automatically, when I just added tablename_id?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check with JetBrains documentation or ask their tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That relationships are virtual. It means that they don't exist in the database, but DataGrip creates them based on names trying to guess what connections your database has. If you don't want to see them on the diagram, turn the displaying of them off via that button: [image]

Comment: Helped me. Thank you!